# How to do a side by side form controlled by a button in C#

Tags: c#, forms, button, filter, switch-statement

I have to make a table with possible filters in C#.

So I want to show the filters in another form using a button which switches between "Show filters >" and "< Hide filters" in the main form.

I open the filters form side by side the main form by using this code:

```
var frmFilters = new FrmFilterSearch();
frmFilters.SetDesktopLocation(Location.X + Size.Width, Location.Y);

if (!Filters)
   {
        Filters = true;
        btn_show_filters.Text = "< Hide filters";
        frmFilters.Show();
   }
else
   {
        Filters = false;
        btn_show_filters.Text = "Show filters >";
        frmFilters.Hide();
   }
```

The filters form open very well and the button is switching his text, but I can't close (hide) the filters form. If I click again on the button, it opens a new filter form.

I hope someone can help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're creating a new instance of the `Form` each time the button is clicked.

You'll want to create an instance of `FrmFilterSearch` and set its location once, *outside* of the button click event, then show/hide the same Form. I'd suggest using the constructor:

```
FrmFilterSearch frmFilters = new FrmFilterSearch();

public YourConstructor()
{
    frmFilters.SetDesktopLocation(Location.X + Size.Width, Location.Y);
}

private void FilterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Filters)
    {
        Filters = true;
        btn_show_filters.Text = "< Hide filters";
        frmFilters.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        Filters = false;
        btn_show_filters.Text = "Show filters >";
        frmFilters.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: oh thanks ! my bad, i was trying an incorrect way. Thank you a lot